# Yii2 UrlManager

Tags: yii2

Всем привет. Изучаю работу urlmanager в yii2 и не могу разобраться с parseReequest, Создал свой класс

```
public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
{
    if ($route === 'template/view') {
        if (isset($params['id'])) {
            $template = Template::findOne($params['id']);
            if (!empty($template)) {
                $slug = $template->slug;
                return 'template/'.$slug.'/view';
            }
        }
    } elseif ($route === 'template/update') {
        if (isset($params['id'])) {
            $template = Template::findOne($params['id']);
            if (!empty($template)) {
                $slug = $template->slug;
                return 'template/'.$slug.'/update';
            }
        }
    }
}

public function parseRequest ($manager, $request) {
    $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
    if (preg_match('%^template/(\w+)(?:/(\w+))$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
        $template = Template::findOne($params['id']);
        if (!empty($template)) {
            $params['id'] = $template->id;
            return ['template/' . $matches[1], $params];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Не могу понять как распарсить, что  бы автоматически action подставлять! как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `template` у вас модуль или контроллер?

Comment: @Blacknife  template - контроллер

Comment: и к какому экшену контроллера относится данный роут? : `'template/'.$slug.'/update'`

Comment: @Blacknife  // так сначало я собираю ссылку что бы было не `template/view?id=480` или `template/update?id=480` а получили вид `template/slug/view` или `template/slug/update`  - это норм, ссылки преобразуются, а вот как их распарсить и направить не могу сообразить. parseRequest не поддается мне((( ..

Comment: так выложите код второго метода, как пробовали?

Comment: @Blacknife вот тут совсем все плохо `public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

            if (preg_match('%^template/(\w+)(?:/(\w+))$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
                
                $template = Template::findOne($params['id']);
                    
                if(!empty($template)){ 

                    $params['id'] = $template->id;
                    return ['template/'.$matches[1], $params];
                }
            }

            return false;  
        }` не могу понять принцип